# rpy2 plot problems(device not responding) rpy2.rinterface.NULL

Tags: plot, graphics, rpy2

```
Setup: 
1. win10,
2. python3.5/3.6, 
3. R 3.42,
4. rpy2 2.90 or 2.8x
5. Ipython 6.1.0
```

when I use rpy2 as the rpy2 Documentation, there are troubles with the plotting:

```
In [26]: import rpy2.robjects as robjects
...:
...: r = robjects.r
...:
...: x = robjects.IntVector(range(10))
...: y = r.rnorm(10)
...:
...: r.X11()
...:
...: r.layout(r.matrix(robjects.IntVector([1,2,3,2]), nrow=2, ncol=2))
...: r.plot(r.runif(10), y, xlab="runif", ylab="foo/bar", col="red")
...:
Out[26]: rpy2.rinterface.NULL
```

there was a graphic after ploting, but something wrong with the graphic, the title became:R Graphics: Device3 (ACTIVE) (not responding), then python crashed, I need to restart it.

[because my system language is chinese, the tranlation of the  picture title is R Graphics: Device3 (ACTIVE) (not responding)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsbTn.png)

I tried different version of rpy2 or python, they have this problem too.

who can help me?

Comment: Have tried using a different system language like English? Are there reports of this issue to the developer of rpy2?

Comment: There is no official support of rpy2 for Windows. Try Linux in a VM or a Docker container.

Comment: What happens when you remove the instruction r.X11()?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following workaround, it seems needed even in 2019. If a plot is barely or not shown in the preview and the window does not react when clicked: 
Load the plot twice and use r.windows() / r.X11() / r.quartz() in between (graph commands Windows / Unix / Mac according to https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/creating.html --> Viewing Several Graphs, though at least X11() seems to work on Windows as well).
Then use grdevices.dev_off() twice and choose your waiting time in between or execute it just once and close it with an isolated grdevices.dev_off() statement whenever you like.

```
import time
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects.lib import ggplot2
grdevices = importr('grDevices')
rprint = robjects.globalenv.get("print")

pp = ggplot2.ggplot(mtcars) + \
     ggplot2.aes_string(x='wt', y='mpg', col='factor(cyl)') + \
     ggplot2.geom_point() + \
     ggplot2.geom_smooth(ggplot2.aes_string(group = 'cyl'), method = 'lm')

rprint(pp)
r.windows()
rprint(pp)
grdevices.dev_off()

#From here optional, if you want a waiting time
#Elsewise close the plot manually afterwards with grdevices.dev_off()
time.sleep(10)
grdevices.dev_off()
```

And if the window still crashes, execute grdevices.dev_off(), no need to force close

Alternative: do not show the plot at all, but save the picture instead.

```
grdevices.dev_copy(device = r.png, filename = "plot.png", width = 1000, height = 500)
rprint(pp)
grdevices.dev_off()
```